# Using an SQL expression to insert data with SQLAlchemy (and MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I would like to be able to insert data into a MySQL database and have one or more of those columns the result of a MySQL function.  For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE values (a varchar(255), b int, c date);
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) values (null,2,NOW());
```

How do I do this in SQLAlchemy using the table metadata and db engine?  Right now I create a dict of code called `items` and run:

```
connection.execute(table.insert().values(items))
```

But I don't know how to put `NOW()` into items.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ins = table.insert().values(a=None, b=2, c=func.now())
engine.execute(ins)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the example it helped me uncover a little more of what SQLAlchemy is doing!  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/tutorial.html#functions